# Leave useEffect empty dependency giving eslint error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a small problem. And Here is how I want the code to behave.

when the component is mounted call the useEffect only once, but inside the useEffect I am using a value from redux store which require to put in dependancy, which causing an infinit loop

So how do I save the call function only once in the component without useEffect and avoid the infinite loop, or is there another way

Also If I write the logic in a function, it requires the function to be callback and I face the same issue

Here is my implementation:

```
const { price = { min: 5000 } } = useSelector(selectPendingPost);


const savePrice = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      dispatch(
        addFieldsToPendingPost({
          price: { min: value[0], ...(value[1] && { max: value[1] }) },
        })
      );
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

useEffect(() => {
    savePrice([price.min]);
  }, [savePrice]);
```

Comment: What is the eslint error?

Comment: missing dependency error

Comment: Try adding price.min as dependency

Comment: The issue is I don't what the useEffect to trigger everytime price is changed

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add `price.min` as dependency? `price` is an object and is recreated everytime. But `price.min` seems like it's a number, so the dependency will compare its value and this should be constant after the first call of `useEffect`

Comment: it will work this way, but now dispatch is called twice